# Reading from PNG file in Java from using GDAL

Tags: gdal, java, geotools, gdalwarp, png

I've used gdalwarp.exe to project a tif-file from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:32635 and storing it in the PNG-format:

```
gdalwarp.exe -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:32635 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -if GTiff -of PNG -et 0.125 -r cubicspline -co COMPRESS=LZW -co WORLDFILE=YES H:\somlos_8.tif H:\trans32635.png
```

Then I try to read that PNG_file in Java with GDAL:

```
   import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D;
   import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridFormat;
   import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridCoverage2DReader;
   import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder;
   import org.geotools.factory.Hints;
   import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat;

   public class Test {
      public Test() {   
         AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat("H:\\trans32635.png");
         Hints hints=null;;
         GridCoverage2DReader reader = null;
         if (!format.getName().equals("Unknown Format"))
            hints = new Hints();
         if (format instanceof GeoTiffFormat) {
            hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
         }
         try {
            reader = format.getReader("H:\\trans32635.png", hints);
            GridCoverage2D cov = null;
            cov = reader.read(null);
         } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
  }
```

The problem is reading "GridCoverage2D" from the reader "cov = reader.read(null);", where it crashes. It works with the original TIF-file.
I'm running the JAVA-program on Windows 10 and using GDAL 3.21.

Comment: That code snippet won't compile, let alone work - can you replace it with a small self contained example

Comment: Sorry!  New exampe.

Comment: This line `if (!format.getName().equals("Unknown Format"))` makes me suspicious - what is `format.getName()` at this point?

Comment: It's "WorldImage".

Answer (score 1):

A PNG is a simple image file and has no georeferencing so it can't be read in using the `GridCoverage` module with out some help. You need to add the [`gt-image` module](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/image.html) provided that you also have the matching world file (`.wld` or `.pgw`) that tells GeoTools where to put the raster data.

### Update

You might need to set the CRS explicitly in the code or by creating a `.prj` file to go with your image files.

Comment: I had gt-image added and there was a .wld file I have also copied the .wld to .pgw but there was no difference. I stops here:  java.awt.geom.affineTransform.class (public AffineTransform(AffineTransform Tx) {
        this.m00 = Tx.m00; )

Comment: can you add a link to the tif. png and wld files to your question

Comment: Ian, the files are together 200kb (just a small tile), but I don't have any place for you to download them :-(

Comment: I have one xml file with the projection created by gdalwarp (trans32635.png.aux.xml) next to the .wld and .png files. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I created (trans32635.prj:  PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_34N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",21.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]  but it's the same.